# typescript - dynamic new class object name

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to create a new class objects in loop where I can provide a dynamic name of this class, e.g. I have class "tree":

```
export default class ParentClass {
    // ...
}

export default class Thomas extends ParentClass {
    // ...
}

export default class Paul extends ParentClass {
    // ...
}
```

and loop:

```
const workers = ['Thomas', 'Paul'];
for (const worker of workers) {
    const h = new <worker>();
    // do something with this object
}
```

Is it possible to do this? Project using NodeJS with Express.js.

Comment: Does all the names in the `workers`-array correspond to an existing class?

Comment: @John Yes, I'm not allowing to use "name" of non-existing class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible, either you can put the class constructors right in the array:

```
const workers = [Thomas, Paul];
for (const workerConstructor of workers) {
  const h = new workerConstructor();
  // do something with this object
}
```

Or, put them in a map so you can access them using a string key:

```
const classMap = {
  'Thomas': Thomas,
  'Paul': Paul
}

const workers = ['Thomas', 'Paul'];
for (const workerKey of workers) {
  const h = new classMap[workerKey]();
  // do something with this object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const workers = ['Thomas', 'Paul'];
for (const worker of workers) {
    let c;
    eval("c=new "+worker+"()");
    // do something with this object
}
```